# Emulate battery in charging state

Tags: circuit-analysis, batteries, battery-charging, simulation, emulator

I am trying to build a circuit to emulate a lipo battery. Basically the circuit consists in a power supply to emulate the discharge behaviour and a variable load to eulate the charge behaviour. This is the circuit in a simplified way
[image: Circuit]

This basically generates 2 circuits, one to emulate discharge behaviour (with which I don't have any problem) and one to emulate charge behaviour:

[image: Charging circuit]

The issue that I'm having with this circuit is that, when I am emulating the charging behaviour the voltage generated by the power supply (which I use in the charging stage to emulate the battery voltage when charging) some of it's current is leaking through the variable load as shown in the picture by "Unwanted current". This is making the sensing of the current to be off and obviously to wasted a los of power because of that unwanted current.
[image: Circuit current description]

Is there a way to "block" the current from going to the load? I thought of a diode in the load entrance but that will make the charging current to be blocked as well.
Maybe some way to make the voltage coming out of the power supply to be only use as reference to maintain a battery charging voltage and not having that much current going through the load but how can I do that? Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why not have that relay switch between "charge" and "discharge" mode, so that you have an open relay contact in series with the "discharge" source while in "charge" mode?

Comment: Fyi, some bench power supplies can sink current. I used mine to test a low current battery charger just the other day.

Comment: Is this a one-off or intended for mass production? If the former, e-loads with built in battery emulation are available.

Comment: Yeah I know there are some power supplies that can basically emulate batteries but they are really expensive and I am trying to emulate with this circuit. @Hearth where are you suggesting me to put the second relay? I don't understand it.

Comment: @danielcastellanos I'm saying still use one relay, with common on the emulator terminal, NC on the "charge" load and NO on the "discharge" source.

Comment: Yeah the issue with that is that I still need the power supply connected to emulate battery voltage when charging